# Sending a reset in TCP/IP Socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, networking, reset

I am using python’s socket.py to create a connection to an ftp-server. Now I want to reset the connection (send a RST Flag) and listen to the response of the ftp-server. (FYI using socket.send('','R') does not work as the OS sends FIN flag instead of RST.)

Comment: Why do you want to reset the connection?

Comment: replicating a malicious ftpclient

Comment: Related: [resetting a TCP connection from the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065411/427158)

Answer (score 47):

Turn the SO_LINGER socket option on and set the linger time to 0 seconds.  This will cause TCP to abort the connection when it is closed, flush the data and send a RST.  See section 7.5 and example 15.21 in UNP.

In python:

```
def client(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    s.connect((host, port))
    l_onoff = 1                                                                                                                                                           
    l_linger = 0                                                                                                                                                          
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER,                                                                                                                     
                 struct.pack('ii', l_onoff, l_linger))
    # send data here
    s.close()
```

Comment: It will cause TCP to abort the connection when closed, *throw away* any pending data, and send an RST.

Comment: Just some more info on this for those curious: SO_LINGER with a time of 0 seconds means the TCP stack won't "linger around" on close(): it will discard any unsent data and send a RST instead of a FIN. For more info read [this](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=2982) and [this](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_conn.htm).

Comment: Note that if you are using this code in the Microsoft Windows environment then you need to replace the 'ii' in the call to struct.pack() with 'hh'. Windows uses shorts in struct linger, where Linux uses ints.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement your own behavior over connections I think you should try using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It is a really useful library/tool. It lets you play with IP/TCP/UDP/ICMP packages.

Answer (score 3):

To send an RST on a TCP connection, set the `SO_LINGER` option to `true` with a zero timeout, then close the socket. This resets the connection. I have no idea how to do that in Python, or indeed whether you can even do it.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to a server, send data and then RST (instead of FIN):
(I tested it on Windows)

```
import struct
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from _socket import SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER

ip="192.168.1.10" #change it to real IP address.
port=8084 #change it to real port number.
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
s.connect((ip, port))
#send data to server (optional)
s.close()
```