# How to stop a TCPServer, how to remove TIME_WAIT sockets

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu, tcpserver

I wrote my two classes

```
class RequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

class Server(socketserver.TCPServer):
```

so that an unique Server can handle regular browser-, ajax- and websocket requests.
It works fine.

I just can't find the way to terminate the Server. So I kill the process.

[EDIT] I need to shutdown the server when it receives a shutdown request from the browser. I tried setting `self.__shutdown_request` True but it didn't work.

Beside, after I have closed the browser and killed the process, netstat tells me there are some sockets
still alive using the Server's port, with TIME_WAIT status. So I have to wait for them to die before to use the same port again.

**How do I terminate the Server?**

**Is there a way to remove those sockets?**

Comment: Can't help you with the first issue, but to avoid sockets hanging around in TIME_WAIT state you can set SO_LINGER ON with a timeout of 0, as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439790/sending-a-reset-in-tcp-ip-socket-connection

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try the method `Server.shutdown` to shutdown the server. As explained by the Python docs, this method tell the `Server.serve_forever` loop to stop and wait until it does.
By the way, although you can set SO_LINGER ON to avoid the TIME_WAIT state of your TCP sockets, it is not encouraged to do so. An alternative is to set the SO_REUSEADDR before you bind the server port.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in a terminal window to kill the TCP port 28355 to stop the TIME_WAIT socket:

`npx kill-port 28355`

In my python socket server script I used the following lines:

`import os os.system("npx kill-port 28355")`

This command solves the "Address already in use" error. It was the only solution that solved the error out of all the other solutions I found, like enabling the `SO_REUSEADDR` option.