# how to reproduce "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

I have learned the differences between the two infamous errors in tcp:

- `[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`
- `[Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Both errors are one side of the tcp connection closed for unknown reason, and the other side still communicate with it.

- when the other side `write` something, `Broken pipe` is thrown
- when the other side `read` something, `Connection reset by peer` is thrown

I was able to reproduce `Broken pipe` using Python codes below.

```
# tcp_server.py
def handler(client_sock, addr):
    try:
        print('new client from %s:%s' % addr)
    finally:
        client_sock.close()   # close current connection directly

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('', 5500))
    sock.listen(5)

    while 1:
        client_sock, addr = sock.accept()
        handler(client_sock, addr)
```

As for client,

```
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.connect(('', 5500))
>>> sock.send('a')
1
>>> sock.send('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

When the client first `send`, a `RST` packet is sent from server to client, from this moment on, `send` will always throw `Broken pipe`.

Everything above is within my understanding. However when client read from server , it always return empty string instead of throw `Connection reset by peer`

```
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.connect(('', 5500))
>>> sock.recv(1024)
''
>>> sock.recv(1024)
''
>>> sock.recv(1024)
''
>>> sock.recv(1024)
```

I am confused at this, or generally how to reproduce the `Connection reset by peer` ?

Comment: You send a reset with the SO_LINGER option outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6440364/642070

Comment: @tdelaney still recv empty string

Comment: It worked for me. I had to add a short wait in the server so that the RST doesn't come back with the connect.

Answer (score 8):

You can set the socket "linger" option to 0 and close the socket to send a reset. Updating your server

```
import socket
import struct
import time

# tcp_server.py
def handler(client_sock, addr):
    try:
        print('new client from %s:%s' % addr)
        time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        client_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER,
            struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
        client_sock.close()   # close current connection directly

if __name__ == '__main__':

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('', 5500))
    sock.listen(5)

    while 1:
        client_sock, addr = sock.accept()
        handler(client_sock, addr)
```

And running this client

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('', 5500))
print(sock.recv(1024))
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpclient.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(sock.recv(1024))
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Thanks. your codes did throw the exception. Then another question : why did `send` and `recv` behave differently at this