# Ignore/discard incoming HTML after sending a GET to a socket

Tags: python, html, sockets, freeze

I use the following code snippet to send data to a web server.  In this case, I do not care at all about the HTML page that the server wants to send back.  The server supports other clients that need that data, so I can't eliminate the quantity of HTML that is going to come back at my Python on Raspberry Pi.  What I'm seeing is that frequently the ESP-8266 server seems to hang waiting to send data back to my Python/Pi client. Like the Pi stops accepting the data until something times out.  As a test, I eliminated 50% of the web page being served, and it works fine on the Pi/Python.  Should I be doing something in the python code to set buffer size or issue a command to ensure the data is discarded and not kept in a socket buffer somewhere that could perhaps overflow or something that causes python/pi to stop accepting server data?

```
htmlString = ("/Interior, /COLOR,r="+str(dimPixelIn[0]).zfill(3)+",g="+str(dimPixelIn[1]).zfill(3)+",b="+str(dimPixelIn[2]).zfill(3))
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(awningAddress, timeout=0.3)
try:
    conn.request("GET", htmlString)
except socket.timeout as sto:
    print("Error")
except http.client.HTTPException as Exc:
    print("Error")
finally:    
    conn.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

A TCP connection consists of 2 almost independent unidirectional streams. The `conn.close()` closes only the stream from the client to the server. The connection from the server to the client is still open and the server still sends data.

I know 2 option how to prevent server send data that are not necessary.

- Do not use the `GET` method. Use the `OPTIONS` method. If server supports the OPTIONS method (and it should) then handled it like a GET request but it sends HTTP response with HTTP headers but without body.
- Reset the connection instead closing it. You can reset connection when set SO_LINGER socket option - see [Sending a reset in TCP/IP Socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439790/sending-a-reset-in-tcp-ip-socket-connection) for example.